# Element opacity but not border

Tags: css, border, opacity

Well, I have this question and I see that someone already asked something similar but this I don't understand yet.

What I want to do is to set a opacity of 0.7 to an element but just to the content and not to the border, I want the border to stay full color. Some example code here:

```
input#element{
    width: 382px;
    height: 26px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

The result is that my input element has the opacity but even the border, Can someone tell me how to set the opacity just in the content but not the border?

Thank's.

Comment: The easiest way would be to give the border to another element that surrounds the input.

Comment: @RohitAzad Thank you so much. I don't know how I didn't imagine this. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @RohitAzad your solution not effect on text, check mine

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `rgba` syntax both for color and background and not use opacity for whole element

[**demo dabblet**](http://dabblet.com/gist/4146745)

```
input {
    width: 382px;
    height: 26px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see that the question was about an input element, but maybe my answer will help somebody else, so here we go.

As other posters have said, you can use the `rgba` syntax to define your background color.

If there are nested elements in the one you want to change, you also can apply the `opacity` to them with this css:

```
#element > * {
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

Here is an example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynNj7/2/)

If you want a background-image for your element, I think the best way is still to wrap it in a container with the border.

Answer (score 1):

opacity background but not border css

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nnt25251325/Dnfqm/1/)

html

```
<div id="element"></div>
```

css

```
#element{
    width: 156px;
    height: 156px;
    border: 2px solid #96d5ea;
    background:rgba(150, 213, 234,1);
    margin: 35px auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

#element:hover {
    background:rgba(150, 213, 234,0);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background:rgba` property for your desired results that will only effect your `parent` not the `child` and also for the `border` of `parent`.

**CSS**

```
input#element{
    width: 382px;
    height: 26px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xsyHV/3/)

Comment: you forgot to apply semi-transparence to the text inside input