# In div, how do I make the background transparent, but not the outline?

Tags: css, html, transparency, opacity

Title says it all, I want to have the background at 50% opacity and the outline non-transparent.

```
div
{
opacity:0.5;
Border:1px solid #000000;
background-color:#000000;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559188/element-opacity-but-not-border

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use rgba

the a is for opacity of the background... which can be 0 through 1 , 0 is invisible, 1 is fully visible..

```
div {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Freakin' lovely! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

setting `opacity` will automatically set anything related to that class, including outline and even child nodes.

You can use `rgba()` to make a semi-transparent background color.

like this:

```
background-color:#000000; //fall-back for old browsers that don't support rgba
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); //set background color. red=0, green=0, blue=0, alpha=0.5
```

http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/